# (c++) Syntax errors for node header

Tags: c++, list, syntax, token, nodes

I am getting ALLOT of syntax errors and token errors for this header.

```
#pragma once
#include "Book.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;
/**
* This is a node class, they will hold object
* data and nodes will be utilized in List class
*/
class Node
{
public:
    /**
    * Purpose: Default constructor
    * Parameters: none
    * Returns: none
    * Pre-conditions: none
    * Post-conditions: NULL node is added to Linked List
    */
    Node();

    /**
    * Purpose: De-constructor
    * Parameters: none
    * Returns: none
    * Pre-conditions: none
    * Post-conditions: Node is deleted
    */
    ~Node();

    /**
    * Purpose: Parameterized constructor
    * Parameters: Book
    * Returns: none
    * Pre-conditions: none
    * Post-conditions: node is added to Linked List
    *                  with data
    */
    Node(Book* B);

    /**
    * Purpose: Name getter
    * Parameters: none
    * Returns: Book
    * Pre-conditions: Item name is not NULL
    * Post-conditions: none
    */
    Book* getBook();

    /**
    * Purpose: Next node getter
    * Parameters: none
    * Returns: Pointer for next node in list
    * Pre-conditions: Must have another node in list ahead of this
    * Post-conditions: none
    */
    Node* getNextNode();

    /**
    * Purpose: Next node setter
    * Parameters: pointer for next node in list
    * Returns: none
    * Pre-conditions: none
    * Post-conditions: List has new node ahead of this
    */
    void setNextNode(Node* a);

private:
    Book* thisBook;
    string itemName;
    string itemType;
    int itemNum;
    Node* nextNode;
};
```

Everything seems to be in order, but I am getting these errors

```
Error   C2061   syntax error: identifier 'Book'     38  

Error   C2535   'Node::Node(void)': member function already defined or declared     38  

Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ';' before '*'    47  

Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    47  

Error   C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';'   47  

Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ';' before '*'    68  

Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    68  

Error   C2238   unexpected token(s) preceding ';'   68
```

I am creating a linked list and these types of errors are also appearing on my List.h file. Is there some sort of deceleration that I am missing? As for the second error, it's pointing to the parameterized constructor.

EDIT: Book definition code

```
#pragma once
#include "Node.h"
#include "List.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;

/**
* Class designed to store information
* of a book. This class is the BASE.
*/
class Book
{
private:
    string author;
    string title;
    double price;

public:

    /**
    * Purpose: Default constructor
    * Parameters: none
    * Returns: none
    * Pre-conditions: none
    * Post-conditions: none
    */
    Book();

    /**
    * Purpose: Constructor
    * Parameters: author, address, price
    * Returns: none
    * Pre-conditions: none
    * Post-conditions: variables saved
    */
    Book(string, string, double);

    /**
    * Purpose: Getter for Author class
    * Parameters: none
    * Returns: Author class
    * Pre-conditions: none
    * Post-conditions: none
    */
    string getAuthor();

    /**
    * Purpose: Getter for title
    * Parameters: none
    * Returns: title
    * Pre-conditions: title must have been saved
    * Post-conditions: none
    */
    string getTitle();

    /**
    * Purpose: Getter for price
    * Parameters: none
    * Returns: price
    * Pre-conditions: price must have been saved
    * Post-conditions: none
    */
    double getPrice();
};
```

Comment: the compiler log is already your good friend - read it carefully and try to understand what each mistake is. Something like `missing ;` should be obvious

Comment: I don't suppose Book.h includes Node.h?

Comment: @aschepler I am sure you are right.:)

Comment: It does include Node.h

Comment: The problem seems to be in your definition of the `Book` object. perhaps you could show us the code for that?

Comment: @Daniel Espinel: The problem is caused by attempting to rely on circular header inclusion. Don't create circular inclusion - it never solves anything.

Comment: @AnT Can you elaborate on that? My instructor never mentioned circular header inclusion before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both of these headers are included in the same file, depending on the order it will try to define `Node` before `Book`

In order to account for this dependency, either make sure they are included in the right order, or declare `Book` without defining it before `class Node`

```
class Book;

class Node
{
    ...
};
```

Comment: These are separate header files. Thanks for the info though.

Comment: Tried this and combined List and Node. It worked! THANKS!